# add another file to the end of the current file by using functions in c++

Tags: c++

I want to copy the content of another file to the end of the current file I am using.  The code runs, but nothing happens in the file.  This is part of the code:

```
void copyFile(fstream &TEXT, char *Name){
    TEXT.close();
    TEXT.open(Name, ios::in);
    char* character = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    cin.clear();
    //cin.getline(character, 1000, '\0');
    cout << "Enter File Name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(Name, 100, '\n');;
    TEXT.open(Name, ios::out | ios::app);
    TEXT << " " << character;
    cout << "Done copying..\n";
}
```

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++. For strings use `std::string`.

Comment: Also, `TEXT.open(..., ios::in);` followed by `TEXT.open(..., ios::out | ios::app);`?

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++? It looks like C (except for the `cin` usage). Also; could you post a [mcve] rather than a code snippet?

Comment: Would recommend getting a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/9254539) instead of whatever you're learning "C++" from currently.

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of problems with this code:

- allocating `character` using `malloc()` instead of `new[]`, and then not reading anything into `character` before writing it to file, and not deallocating `character`.
- opening `TEXT` with `ios::in`, not reading anything from it, and then reopening it with `ios::out | ios::app` without `close()`'ing it first.
- reading user input into the memory that `Name` points to, which may or may not be large enough to hold the user input, or may be pointing at read-only memory, etc.

It is really difficult to figure out what your code is *trying* to do.  But I *think* you might try something more like this instead:

```
void copyFile(fstream &TEXT, char *Name) {
    TEXT.close();
    TEXT.open(Name, ios::in);
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << TEXT.rdbuf();
    TEXT.close();
    cout << "Enter File Name: ";
    string otherName;
    getline(cin, otherName);
    TEXT.open(otherName.c_str(), ios::out | ios::app);
    TEXT << " " << ss.str();
    cout << "Done copying..\n";
}
```

Or, maybe you want something more like this:

```
void copyFile(fstream &TEXT, char *Name){
    ifstream ifs(Name);
    cout << "Enter File Name: ";
    string otherName;
    getline(cin, otherName);
    TEXT.close();
    TEXT.open(otherName.c_str(), ios::out | ios::app);
    TEXT << " " << ifs.rdbuf();
    cout << "Done copying..\n";
}
```

Or, maybe simply this:

```
void copyFile(fstream &TEXT, char *Name) {
    ifstream ifs(Name);
    TEXT << " " << ifs.rdbuf();
    cout << "Done copying..\n";
}
```